# How to find memory used by ruby object?

Tags: ruby, memory-management

Is there any function in ruby, to find memory used by ruby object.
Similar to how C has the `sizeof()` function and PHP has the `memory_get_usage()` function.  Does ruby have an equivalent function/method?

Comment: Probably a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973094/how-to-measure-the-size-of-a-ruby-object

Comment: I'm curious: what is the purpose of your question? Do you want to be able to know the size of an object or are you trying to figure out how much memory have a large number of certain objects will take?

Comment: This should be useful: https://gist.github.com/camertron/2939093

Comment: This question is a duplicate.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973094/how-to-measure-the-size-of-a-ruby-object

Answer (score 8):

`ObjectSpace#memsize_of` [from the Ruby docs:](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/objspace/rdoc/ObjectSpace.html#method-c-memsize_of)

> Return consuming memory size of obj.

```rb
[1] pry(main)> require 'objspace'
=> true
[2] pry(main)> ObjectSpace.memsize_of('')
=> 40
[3] pry(main)> ObjectSpace.memsize_of([])
=> 40
[4] pry(main)> ObjectSpace.memsize_of(1..100)
=> 40
[5] pry(main)> ObjectSpace.memsize_of('X' * 100)
=> 141
[6] pry(main)> ObjectSpace.memsize_of(('X' * 100).chars)
=> 840
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a stretch, but if your goal is to look for a memory leak, rather than see the size of individual objects, you might look at `object_count(cls)`, as in:

```
>> ObjectSpace.each_object(Object).count
=> 114629
>> ObjectSpace.each_object(Array).count
=> 10209
```

etc.  FWIW, symbols are a little different: you can get the count of symbols via:

```
>> Symbol.all_symbols.count
=> 17878
```

To find out if you have a leak of not, you can manually call GC, count your objects, run your code for a while, call GC again, then see if any object count has grown significantly.

Of course, this doesn't tell you the size of each object, just how many of each class are allocated.

There's also [memprof](https://github.com/ice799/memprof), but I admit that I haven't used that yet.

Comment: This is the number of objects in memory. The original question, as I understand it, asks how to find out the memory usage (in bytes) of a single object.

Comment: @Ariejan: Fully agree.  That's why I said "*if* your goal is to look for a memory leak, rather than see the size of individual objects..."